# how do I set the discount as buy any 3 products of a brand and get 10 $ discount.

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

I have been trying out a discount rule but couldn't achieve it in the desired way. I have created a rule in which buy any 3 products of a brand and get 10 AED discount. The rule works perfectly if I add three 3 quantities of a single product, But doesnt work when I add three different products of 1 quantity each.

Answer (score 0):

Check brand attribute in admin panel , it should be "yes" for use in promo rule condition.

Comment: Yes I have already set that. It works fine for one product with 3 qty under the same brand, but doesnt work if I add 3 products of the same brand with 1 qty each